# How do I align the caption of these two pictures in my minipage at same `height´?

Tags: floats, captions, minipage

It might be a silly question, but it is bothering me that I cannot fix it at the moment.

```
\medskip   
\begin{figure}[h]  
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{bilayer.JPEG}  
  \medskip  
  \caption{3D illustration of the membrane of the polymersome, which consists of a   hydrophillic bilayer at the in- and outside of the biodegradable aliphatic core. This   membrane protects the aqueous core from the environment.}  
  \label{bilayer}  
\end{minipage}%  
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[scale=1.5]{polymersome.JPEG}  
  \caption{Schematic view of polymersome \cite{polymersome1}}  
  \label{polymersome}  
\end{minipage}  
\end{figure}%
```

At the moment it looks like this..[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, now we know how it looks like but how *should* it look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two sets of side-byu-side minipages; the top set has `b` (bottom) alignment for the images and the second set has `t` (top) alignment for the captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}  
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}  
\end{minipage}%  
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.7\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-b}  
\end{minipage}
\par
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
  \caption{3D illustration of the membrane of the polymersome, which consists of a   hydrophillic bilayer at the in- and outside of the biodegradable aliphatic core. This   membrane protects the aqueous core from the environment.}  
  \label{bilayer}  
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth}  
  \caption{Schematic view of polymersome \cite{polymersome1}}  
  \label{polymersome}  
\end{minipage}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks

- I added

  ```
  \captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
  ```

  from the `caption` package so the narrow caption looks better, but this is just a suggestion; instead of this you could increase the width for the left-hand-side `minipage`s (decreasing that from the right-hind-side, of course).
- Using `[h]` as placement specifier is a recipe for disaster. Either use something less restrictive, as `[htp]`, or better yet, don't use the placement specifier at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`floatrow` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{floatrow}[2]
    \ffigbox{
      \caption{3D illustration of the membrane of the polymersome, which consists of a 
        hydrophillic bilayer at the in- and outside of the biodegradable aliphatic core. This 
        membrane protects the aqueous core from the environment.\label{fig:first}}
      }{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{
      \caption{Schematic view of polymersome.\label{fig:second}}
      }{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-b}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The interface is slightly different than your regular usage of graphics inclusion and captions, but it interfaces well with [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float), and allows for easy styling of either component.

Comment: Thanks! But it does not work together with the float package in my document? I did have a minipage somewhere else in the document which now is changed in a bad way, I will try to use the floatrow again! Do you prefer the package floatrow above the package float?

Comment: \begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{PEO.JPEG}
  \bigskip
  \caption{PEO}
  \label{PEO}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.85]{PCL.JPEG}
  \medskip
  \caption{PCL}
  \label{PCL}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \bigskip
  \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{polymersomePEOPCL.JPEG}
  \caption{Polymersome of block co-polymer PEO-PCL}
  \label{PEO-PCL}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}%  The captions are not included anymore because of the package floatrow, correct?

Comment: @W.v.Ekeren: From the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf): "This package was created as extension of the `float` package. The `floatrow` package borrows core code from the `float` [..] package, so you *must not* load this package." It's an entire interface change, but it allows for some nifty things, especially that you don't have to box (sub-)figure content in a `minipage` for alignment - it does this out-of-the-box.